# How to disable the stencil

Tags: c, opengl

I am developing a small tool. I want to draw a geometry where I have already used stencil. How do I do that?

```
// drawing stencil
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glColorMask(false, false, false, false);
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0, 1);

// drawing geometry
glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0, 1);
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to draw your geometry stenciled out, then you need the stencil test enabled for that, not disabled. But you disable stencil testing in the very last line of code you posted.

Comment: how can i draw rectangle in a hole?, where this hole is created by stencil.